# Are Spring Data Repositories and JdbcTemplate sharing the same transaction context?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-transactions

I struggle to find documentation on that topic.
I've been through [Spring official transactionnal handling documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html), and a few SO posts that point toward a yes, but that's not what I'm seeing in practice.

Considering a Spring Boot application, with `@EnableTransactionManagement`, `@EnableJpaRepositories` (using Hibernate and Postgres).
I have the following code:

`BusinessService`:

```
@Transactional
public save(BuildingDTO dto) {
  var building = Building.from(dto);
  var apartments = Apartment.from(dto); 
  
  this.buildingRepository.save(building);
  this.saveAllJdbc(apartments);
}

private saveAllJdbc(List<Apartment> apartments) {
  String insertQuery = "...";
  jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
    insertQuery,
    apartments,
    100,
    (ps, apartment) -> // set ps values
  );
}
```

With the repository define as `BuildingRepository extends CrudRepository<Building, UUID>`, which means the save method is transactional.

Today my issue is that `saveAllJdbc` triggers the foreign key constraint, saying the referred building does not exist. Which means it is not aware of the current transaction.

I made it work by either using only `Spring CrudRepository` methods, or only `JdbcTemplate` methods, in both cases, the transactions were handled as defined in the documentation.

Are Spring Repository default implementation and JdbcTemplate methods supposed to share the transaction context? Or is it a known limitation?

Comment: I think you're invalidly assuming that the call to `save(…)` actually already triggers SQL statements. That can, but doesn't have to be the case as the JPA provider is free to delay any DML statements until transaction commit to be able to batch them. Does the outcome change if you switch to `JpaRepository` and call `saveAndFlush()`?

Comment: Yes, I had tried this calling .flush() and it worked indeed, but I assumed flush would commit the transaction, but looking at the doc' it was a wrong assumption again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with transactions and everything with how JPA works.

When you tell JPA to save data it doesn't do that.
Or at least it has the option to not do that.
Instead it will just keep a reference to the data and will *eventually* save it.
*Eventually* typically means at the end of a transaction.

`JdbcTemplate` on the other hand does nothing fancy and will just execute the SQL statement.

As Oliver Drotbohm wrote, you can solve this problem by triggering a flush event by using `JpaRepository.saveAndFlush()` instead of `save()`.